# How to replace on div with another on hover (CSS ONLY)

Tags: html, css, display

I have two boxes that one is hidden and one is visible. I want to make it work in a way that when the default box is hover, it fades out and the box with display none gets visible.

Here is the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/4rnqmmph/) that doesnt work the way I want it because the once box one is hover, it is still visible, while i want it to go `display: none`.

```css
.box1, .box2{
  width:100px;
  height 100px;
  border:1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
}

.box1{
  display: block;
}

.box2{
  display: none;
}

.box1:hover ~ .box2{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <p>data 1</p>
</div>

<div class="box2">
  <p>data 2</p>
</div>
```

It could be better if it is animated once the boxes switch.

Similar questions have been asked but they all asked for JavaScript. I prefer CSS only.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a wrapper to the two div with the following css:

```
.wrapper {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red; //for visuals
}
```

And you seem to forgot to hide `.box1`

```css
.box1,
.box2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.box1 {
  display: block;
}

.box2 {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}

.wrapper:hover .box1 {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper:hover .box2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box1">
    <p>data 1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="box2">
    <p>data 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you add the fade in and out effect to it as well? I tried `-webkit-transition: display 600ms ease 0ms;` in the `.wrapper` class but doesnt work.

Comment: Unfortunately, `transition` does not work in `display: none`, another kind of triggering the display should be used if you want to have transition

Answer (score 3):

Try this. I have added one extra div to wrap `box1` and `box2` and some css.

```css
.box1, .box2{
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  border:1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
  transition:0.5s;
}
.box2 {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;  
}
.box-wrap:hover .box2{
  opacity:1;
  transform:translateY(0px);  
}
.box-wrap:hover .box1{
  opacity:0;
  height:0; 
}
.box-wrap{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-wrap">
  <div class="box1">
    <p>data 1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="box2">
    <p>data 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is will be quite bothersome especially in responsiveness, since `.box2` will need to be exactly on `.box1`'s place, and `.box1` is not always on the top left part of the document

Comment: @Swellar ok but its depend on its parent div because parent div has `relative` value.

Answer (score 3):

***This will work fine for you.***

I have used some transition to go with your need.

your need can only be achieved by wrapping a `div` around your `.box1` and `.box2`.

```css
.box1,
.box2 {
  width: 100px;
  height 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.4s;
}

.box1 {
  display: block;
}

.box2 {
  max-height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
}
.main_box{
 display:inline-block;
}

.main_box:hover .box1{
  max-height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.main_box:hover .box2{
  max-height: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_box">
  <div class="box1">
    <p>data 1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="box2">
    <p>data 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this was helpfull for you.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to Mr **@Swellar** answer's, I noticed that you would like to add a transition effect.

hence you have to set `position: absolute` for both boxses,
then *onhover* you will switch between `opacity: 0;visibility: hidden` and `opacity: 1;visibility: visible` instead of `display: none` and `display: block`, see the following snippet for more details:

```css
.box1,
.box2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 600ms ease;;
}

.box1 {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: red;
}

.box2 {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: green;
}

.wrapper {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper:hover .box1 {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.wrapper:hover .box2 {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box1">
    <p>data 1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="box2">
    <p>data 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```css
.box1, .box2{
  width:100px;
  height 100px;
  border:1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
  float: left;
}

.box1{
  display: block;
  background: red;
}

.box2{
  display: none;
  margin-left: -102px;
  background: green;
}
.box1:hover{
  opacity:0;
}
.box1:hover ~ .box2{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <p>data 1</p>
</div>

<div class="box2">
  <p>data 2</p>
</div>
```