# How to manage state on a single react element for hover effect?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, hover, jsx

I'm trying to setup a simple 'icon to text' hover effect for my portfolio website in React. When I set it up it changes ALL of the icons on hover, I just want to change the one icon at a time.

```
export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isHover: false
    };

    this.onMouseEnterHandler = this.onMouseEnterHandler.bind(this);
    this.onMouseLeaveHandler = this.onMouseLeaveHandler.bind(this);
  }

  onMouseEnterHandler() {
    this.setState({
      isHover: true
    });
  }

  onMouseLeaveHandler() {
    this.setState({
      isHover: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="home">
      <div className="hamburger-icon"></div>
        <section className="info-section">
          <div className="logo">M</div>
          <div className="info-box-top">
            <a onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnterHandler} onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeaveHandler} className="home active" id="one" href="/">
              { this.state.isHover
                  ? <span>Home</span>
                  : <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} />
              }
            </a>
            <a id="two" href="/about"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser} /></a>
            <a id="three" href="/skills"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCog} /></a>
            <a id="four" href="/gallery"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEye} /></a>
            <a id="five" href="/contact"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEnvelope} /></a>
          </div>
```

Comment: Honestly, you should just use [CSS to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47427056/1218980).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace on div with another on hover (CSS ONLY)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427056/how-to-replace-on-div-with-another-on-hover-css-only)

Comment: @AsiaArgento1 check this solution created as per your requirement https://stackoverflow.com/a/59573528/6544460

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage it through css only but if you want this to manage form javascript than you can manage state of each individual element. please check my codesandbox link for your refrence. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-1nyfs

Answer (score 0):

Optimized code

```
let arr = [
  { id: "one", href: "/", icon: faHome, name: "Home" },
  { id: "two", href: "/about", icon: faUser, name: "About" },
  { id: "three", href: "/skills", icon: faCog, name: "Skills" },
  { id: "four", href: "/gallery", icon: faEye, name: "Gallary" },
  { id: "five", href: "/contact", icon: faEnvelope, name: "Contact" }
];
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isHover: false
  };

  onMouseEnterHandler = selected => {
    console.log(selected);
    this.setState({
      isHover: selected
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="info-box-top">
        {arr.map(a => (
          <a key={a.id}
            onMouseEnter={() => this.onMouseEnterHandler(a)}
            id={a.id}
            href={a.href}
          >
            {this.state.isHover.id === a.id ? (
              <span>{a.name}</span>
            ) : (
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={a.icon} />
            )}
          </a>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/hover-demo-obbcg)

Comment: THANK YOU!! THANK YOU!! this is exactly what I wanted

Comment: @AsiaArgento1 please accept/vote for this if it's helpful for you.